CPU is idle, but huge load, and NFS client stop responding
We have troubles with NFS server. There is 30TB of small files (mail server NFS). After some hours first or second client (where are mail services) stop responding on services ports, because there is not possible open file from NFS. Listing is possible.
Load is very huge (on screen is 400, but after few minutes is 10000). CPU is idle.
I tried everything. There is not connection to max open files, max tcp, etc.
Here is mount point. Client is RockyLinux 8
192.168.91.7:/iwdata/mail on /data type nfs4 (rw,noatime,vers=4.1,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,namlen=255,acregmin=1800,acregmax=1800,acdirmin=1800,acdirmax=1800,soft,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.91.12,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.91.7)



Hello, I'd start to investigate the 3 top processes shown in your image: "pop3" (user icewarp : your mailing system?), and the 2 below it. The "pop3" one especially, it is probably not normal that it uses that much cpu time and memory.

possibilities to try to investigate it : strace (but will be extremely verbose, so better just trace the "OPENS" calls and similar, to see on what it is working, and not trace everything (especially under that load)

@OlivierDulac: That high load probably means very little here: load average basically means "(weighted average over recent time of) number of processes that are runnable OR waiting on disk I/O", and "disk I/O" includes NFS. So if you have an NFS server that isn't responding, and processes start to block as a result, then each blocking process counts towards the load average - even though they're not doing anything other than waiting for the NFS server to respond. Running ps -aux will show these processes in D state; running strace on one of these may show which file it's blocked on.

"CPU is idle"... no, it's 51.6% busy in your screenshot.  Which on a modern Hyper-Threaded processor probably means every single core is 100% busy.

Is the NFS server actually up and responding? Note that it's possible that listing files is possible even if the server is down if those directories are cached. What is the mail server used (especially for that huuuuuge pop3 process)? Is there a single pop3? Is icewarp an end-user? Do they have an extremely large mailbox?

@OlivierDulac POP3, it is normal :). I seen than many php-fpm process was in D state, I try strace on them, but permission denied (probably because state).

@jcaron NFS is up, another client can read files without any troubles and fast. It is solution named Icewarp Server - there is 40k users :).

@psmears - I tried strace, but perm. denied because state - any idea how I can do it with this state?

the "perm. denied" is not because of the state, but because of rights:   sudo strace -p pid ... ?

@OlivierDulac I run this as root user, so I think that use sudo is not necessary...?

If you call lsof -n that might yield the listing of open files. From that you can pipe it through all sorts of filters to identify the culprit.
Expect that to take a while however - so I'd call it once and redirect the output to /tmp somewhere.
Alternatively a quicker less informational approach would be to call
 find /proc -maxdepth 3 -path '/proc/*/fd/*' -type l

This will dump the output of every file open, per pid (which should be quicker) to /tmp/results.txt and you can perform post processing on it.
IE
cut -d"/" -f3 /tmp/results.txt  | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1n

Number of open files per pid.
What this might be indicating to you however is that the NFS server is not cooperating with all your open file requests, which is an indication to you you may want to tone down the number of open files permitted to be opened per user (or process at least) or globally on the system.
This isn't going to fix your demand problem (lots of open file requests) but it will prevent the entire system locking up and the NFS server becoming upset with your numbers of requests.
If you find from the output one process has thousand and thousands of files open, you should check cat /proc/<process_id>/limits and see what the max open files limit is set to.
If its set to unlimited or a large number, reduce it in the offending process and see what it does. There are a of lot ways to do this and the approach depends on what the process is that is doing it and how it was started.

Use the LimitNOFILE declaration if the service is a systemd service.
Set a limit on nofile in /etc/security/limits.conf for the affected user if a individual user is responsible.

You can also alter the limit at runtime for running processes using prlimit --nofile <soft>:<hard> -p <pid> but your mileage will vary and I would suggest avoiding doing something like that unless you know what the outcome might be.
After making a change like this expect programs to error out with "Too many open files" errors.
Finally, just to stress, this isn't fixing the demand side problem, just restricting the supply of open files. Effectively its a band-aid to keep your system going at the cost of denying access to resources for greedy (or greedier) processes.
The demand side issue has multiple solutions depending on the cause.

Raise the limit of parallel open file requests on the NFS server if possible.
Manually open a file on the NFS server and time how long it actually takes. Is it actually slow?
Find out why the software is opening all these files and what can be done in configuration or software to alter the behaviour.
Spread the demand to other resources at your disposal.


Thank you, in time when it was blocked I tried your steps, but there was max 8000 files opened by one proccess.
But many proccess are in "D" state.

You can find out why a particular process is stuck, run cat /proc/<pid>/stack and print the result in your question. You should go into /proc/<pid>/fd and run ls -l to get a list of paths to all the 8000  files stuck. Youi'll be looking for a pattern, probably one path will lots of files in it. Print out a sample of that too and add it to the question.
